# Why does Docker need a Union File System

Tags: docker, filesystems, containers

What exactly does Docker do with Union File system (like AUFS) to create the containers ? If Docker had to use a regular file system instead of a union file system what will be the disadvantages ?

I am looking for specific technical details/internals and not a high level answer.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It is used to:

- avoid duplicating a complete set of files each time you run an image as a new container
- isolate changes to a container filesystem in its own layer, allowing for that same container to be restarted from a known content (since the layer with the changes will have been dismissed when the container is removed)

That [UnionFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS):

> implements a [union mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) for other file systems. It allows files and directories of separate file systems, known as branches, to be transparently overlaid, forming a single coherent file system.
>   Contents of directories which have the same path within the merged branches will be seen together in a single merged directory, within the new, virtual filesystem.
>
> This allows a file system to appear as writable, but without actually allowing writes to change the file system, also known as **[copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)**

If you didn't have UnionFS, an 200MB image run 5 times as 5 separates containers would mean 1GB of disk space.

See more at "[How does a Docker image work?](http://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/#how-does-a-docker-image-work)".
For more technical details, see:

- "[Docker storage drivers](http://www.slideshare.net/Docker/docker-storage-drivers)"
- "[Anatomy of a Container: Namespaces, cgroups & Some Filesystem Magic](http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/jpetazzo/anatomy-of-a-container-namespaces-cgroups-some-filesystem-magic-linuxcon)" from [Jérôme Petazzoni (`jpetazzo`)](https://github.com/jpetazzo).

Comment: Plus, for those hosting the docker images on a SAN storage device on the backend, the humongous amount of cache hits must be a storage admin's dream.