# Docker run command from git repo?

Tags: git, docker

Let's say that I have a git repo which contains my new files and docker files (and others) from other git repo.
I want to clone this repo to my own local machine, and then I want to build this repo with docker. So I'll execute

```
docker build -t name:v1 cloned-folder/
```

But, after that, when I type `docker images` I get two images: `name:v1` and `image` from the repo.

I want only have my image. How to do that without uploading to docker.hub?

Or maybe there is an option to run new container from cloned files without build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Dockerfile` starts with "`FROM <image>`", then docker images will always shows both `<image>` (the base image) and `name:v1`.

The fact that the Dockerfile is managed in a git repo is not important.

The OP adds:

> `git clone URL_to_my_repo` and this repo contains repo mentioned earlier with my extra own files.
>   Then `docker build -q -t mynewimage:v1 cloned_folder/`.
>   after that I get two images when I type `docker images`
>
> - image from the `FROM` section of Dockerfile and
>
>   - `mynewimage:v1`.
>       What I want is to have only one image: `mynewimage:v1`.

That is expected (to see 2 images): your second one is built from the layers of the first one: you need both in order for `mynewimage` to work (because of the **[union filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32776204/6309)**).

Comment: Hmm... Let's look on example: https://github.com/setiseta/docker-librenms
there is a docker file that also contains FROM section. When i RUN that i get only one image.
Why ?

one difference is that I use also docker build.

Comment: @KenJohns you did not mention RUN in your question. You mentioned docker build.

Comment: @KenJohns What do you type exactly. What do you see as an exact output? (exact and complete copy/paste)

Comment: OK. With link mentioned earlier i just copy/paste everything on that site (so just RUN command with options) and i get one image (from the FROM sections) and one container. If we are talking about my repo: I clone my repo, build with 'docker build' command that cloned repo, i get two images: one from dockerfile (same as on that link) and second one - created by 'docker build'; and then i execute 'docker run' command with the image id (created by me).

Comment: @KenJohns RUN is a Dockerfile directive, do you mean `docker run`

Comment: What i need is to have only one image. I just forked that git and added some other extra options and now i want to run this container. But how should i do that without hub.docker?

Comment: @KenJohns Let's simplify: what do you type, what do you see, what would you expect to see? I mean the exact complete copy/pasted commands and their output.

Comment: Ok.
`git clone URL_to_my_repo` and this repo contains repo mentioned earlier with my extra own files. Then `docker build -q -t mynewimage:v1 cloned_folder/` after that i get two images when i type `docker images` - image from the `FROM section of Dockerfile` and `mynewimage:v1`. What i want is to have only one image: `mynewimage:v1`. If we look for my posted url to librenms and run those commands, we will get only one image and one running container. By me: two images.