# Pipe RUN's output to ENV in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following command in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "\
  export NODE_VERSION=$(\
    curl -sL https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ |\
    tac |\
    tac |\
    grep -oPa -m 1 '(?<=node-v)(.*?)(?=-linux-x64\.tar\.xz)' |\
    head -1\
  )" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
RUN source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

The following command should store `export NODE_VERSION=6.2.2` in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, but it's not storing anything.

This works however when I'm inside an image with bash and manually entering the following commands.

**Update:**

I changed back the shell from `bash` to the Debian/Ubuntu default `dash`, which is POSIX standard. I removed this line:

```
RUN ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh && ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh.distrib
```

Than I tried to add to the environment variables with `export`:

```
RUN export NODE_VERSION=$(\
  curl -sL https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ |\
  tac |\
  tac |\
  grep -oPa -m 1 '(?<=node-v)(.*?)(?=-linux-x64\.tar\.xz)' |\
  head -1\
)
```

But again, the output is missing at image creation, but works when I running the image with `$ docker run --rm -it debian /bin/sh`. Why?

**Update 2:**

Looks like the final solution should be something like this:

```
RUN NODE_VERSION=$( \
  curl -sL https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ | \
  tac | \
  tac | \
  grep -oPa -m 1 '(?<=node-v)(.*?)(?=-linux-x64\.tar\.xz)' | \
  head -1 \
) && echo $NODE_VERSION

ENV NODE_VERSION $NODE_VERSION
```

`echo $NODE_VERSION` returning `6.2.2` as it should at the execution of the Dockerfile also, but `ENV NODE_VERSION $NODE_VERSION` cannot read this. Is there a way to define variables globally or how can I pass the `RUN`'s output to `ENV`?

**Solution:**

I ended up putting the node.js installation part under the same `RUN` command:

```
RUN NODE_VERSION=$( \
        curl -sL https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ | \
        tac | \
        tac | \
        grep -oPa -m 1 '(?<=node-v)(.*?)(?=-linux-x64\.tar\.xz)' | \
        head -1 \
    ) \
    && echo $NODE_VERSION \
    && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -o "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
    && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
    && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
    && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt
```

Comment: That looks messy in a Dockerfile. Why not place that into a script for the container to run?

Comment: This is needed for the following URL: `https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz` which is interpreted to `https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v6.2.2-linux-x64.tar.xz` for the node.js installation. Unfortunately Node.js repo not offering `https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-latest-linux-x64.tar.xz` archive which will make my question unnecessary.

Comment: I understand why you need it, but you say it is not storing anything, so does that mean the command is not working within the Dockerfile? If so, again I ask, why not place that command in a bash script for the container to run?

Comment: I tried it and the output is still empty. I'm running with `COPY ./node-version.sh /root/ RUN chmod +x $HOME/node-version.sh; /root/node-version.sh`

Answer (score 1):

> **Update:**
>   But again, the output is missing at image creation, but works when I
>   running the image with $ docker run --rm -it debian /bin/sh. Why?

This is because each statement (conventionally started with an uppercase verb like `RUN`, `ADD`, `COPY`, `ENV`, etc) is a brand-new intermediate container.

These intermediate containers do not share the environment (e.g. environment variables) but a **Union File System**. That is, only data saved in file system and those variables defined in Dockerfile (e.g. through `ENV`) deliver through intermediate containers. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775594/why-does-docker-need-a-union-file-system) and [UnionFS Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) if you want to know how UFS works.

If your goal is to install the latest node each time you build the image. How about having a try for [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (Node Version Manager)?

```
ARG UBUNTU=16.04

# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu:${UBUNTU}

# arguments
  ARG NVM=0.33.9
  ARG NODE=node

# update apt
  RUN apt-get update

# Install curl
  RUN apt-get install -y curl

# Set home for NVM
  ENV NVM_DIR=/home/inazuma/.nvm

# Install Node.js with NVM
  RUN mkdir -p ${NVM_DIR} && \
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v${NVM}/install.sh | bash && \
    . ${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install ${NODE}

# The first following line should always be called in each intermediate container
# to gain nvm, node and npm command
  . ${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh && nvm use ${NODE} && \
  npm install -g cowsay && \
  cowsay "Making Docker images is really a headache!"

# Set up your PATH for nvm, node and npm command
  CMD ". ${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh && nvm use ${NODE} && bash"
```

Note that `nvm` does not persist across intermediate containers so you should use `. ${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh` to set up `nvm` command for each new intermediate container.

NVM manages node binary locally, use `nvm use ${NODE}` to include node and npm into PATH. In NVM, `node` stands for an alias of the latest version of Node; therefore, we set `NODE` argument to be `node` (it can also be set to a string of semantic version like `5.0`, `9.11.1`, etc).