# Why && rather than a new RUN

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile

In `Dockerfile`s I'm seeing most people using this syntax

```
RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get install -y libicu-dev
```

over this one

```
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y libicu-dev
```

For me the first one gets only one line (layer) cached while the second caches both (am I wrong ?) and stops as soon as a command is not successful.

Besides I don't find the first one more readable.

So why would we use the first syntax ?

Comment: This is a must read https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [images and layers documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#images-and-layers)

> Each layer is only a set of differences from the layer before it

So for example 2 layers creating different files would not use more disk space. Especially since Docker 17.05 [allows multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers). However, it still could use more space if the second one is entirely modifying files from the first one.

Following [Khapov Igor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47052209/305189) I found out the real answer to the original question in the [best practice doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#apt-get):

> Using `apt-get update` alone in a `RUN` statement causes caching issues and subsequent `apt-get install` instructions fail.

It's actually more about layer dependencies with previous commands for which results can evolve over time like `apt-get update`.

That's why they are telling:

> Always combine `RUN apt-get update` with `apt-get install` in the same `RUN` statement

Answer (score 3):

It is optimisation for docker image layer. I also recommend to read [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)

There is also interesting [presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/Docker/creating-effective-docker-images) from DockerCon EU 2017.

Comment: Thank you for this link, I'll read that and try to find out why we would prefer combining commands.

Answer (score 2):

Lesser the layers, better the image.

Hence, combining commands using && will create a single layer.

Having two RUN will create two layers.

Comment: Why less layers, better image ? If I modify something in a big layer, I'd have to rebuild whole layer. Disk space should not really be impacted here since it is making a diff anyway.

Comment: Images are like virtual file system layers.  Basically, a layer, or image layer is a change on an image, or an intermediate image. Every command you specify (FROM, RUN, COPY, etc.) in your Dockerfile causes the previous image to change, thus creating a new layer. You can think of it as staging changes when you're using git: You add a file's change, then another one, then another one. Hence, lesser the better.

Comment: A layer is a kind of "patch" which contains only differences from the previous one. So there won't be a big gap in terms of disk space used unless we are running commands that reverts entirely the previous layers.

Comment: Yes, agree. Hence all logically similar commands should form a single layer. So, in this particular case, update and install should form a single layer.

Comment: Yes that's the issue that I understand now

Answer (score 0):

**Each command** in a Dockerfile **creates another image layer**.

Combining commands is a way to end up with less layers overall.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#images-and-layers

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
RUN apt-get -y update \
&& apt-get install -y libicu-dev
```

will create one single docker layer and [these lines](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#images-and-layers):

```
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y libicu-dev
```

will create two different layers.

This is the main reason why when you need to install something in your docker machine (ex: via APT) you tend to keep everything in one single line (aka layer)

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers already said, every command generates a layer and it's usually desirable to have the minimum amount of layers per image.

> Each layer is only a set of differences from the layer before it. The layers are stacked on top of each other. When you create a new container, you add a new writable layer on top of the underlying layers.

This means that unless you're going to "squash" your image (which translates in using the `--squash` option during the build), you end up having an image consuming space for nothing.

Example

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends dnsutils
RUN echo $( dig somewhere.nowhere )
RUN apt-get remove --purge dnsutils
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY magicalScript.sh /
CMD /magicalScript.sh
```

In this case you'll have layers containing only overhead:

- 1 with cache coming from `apt-get update`
- 1 with `dnsutils` installed,
- 1 containing the removal of the `dnsutils`
- 1 containing the removal of the cache

The problem is that all those layers remain there and consume space for no reason at all.

Why `squash` is not always a good solution? Because the layers represents a cache as well. And it's extremely useful when you need to perform a lot of builds and you need them to be as fast as possible.

Usually it's good practice to group together operation related the installation of new packages on the OS:

```
# Dockerfile

FROM ubuntu

RUN useradd docker \
    && mkdir /home/docker \
    && chown docker:docker /home/docker \
    && addgroup docker staff

RUN apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ed less locales vim-tiny wget ca-certificates fonts-texgyre \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen en_US.utf8 \
    && /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

CMD ["mySpecialCommand"]
```

Comment: Yes layers remains there, and I'm very grateful for that since I heavily use the cache system. The thing is multiple layers don't necessarily take more disk space than one.

Comment: The overhead is not very significant until you decide to remove stuff. What you need to keep in mind is that for each layer generated your build has to create an intermediate container that gets deleted in the end of the process. Docker uses a union fs. I suggest to give a check to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775594/why-does-docker-need-a-union-file-system#32776204