# Optimizing Laravel docker image

Tags: php, laravel, docker

**Updated**
*I updated the dockerfile for anyone who wants a good dockerfile for their laravel application.*

I'm trying to build a Docker image from my laravel application. My application plus all the dependencies are about 380 MB but the image turns to be 840 MB. I used multistage build as Ivan suggested (Which halved the size of the image, it was 1.2 GB at first). But I still wondering why is my Docker image this big? And how can I reduce the size of the image?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Instruction adapted from https://laravel-news.com/multi-stage-docker-builds-for-laravel

# PHP Dependencies
FROM composer:latest as vendor

COPY database/ database/

COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock

RUN composer install \
    --no-dev \
    --ignore-platform-reqs \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --prefer-dist

# Frontend
FROM node:16.13.1 as frontend

RUN mkdir -p /app/public

COPY package.json webpack.mix.js tailwind.config.js /app/
COPY resources/ /app/resources/
COPY public/ /app/public/
COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm ci && npm run production

# Application
FROM php:7.4-apache

COPY . /var/www/html
COPY --from=vendor /app/vendor/ /var/www/html/vendor/
COPY --from=frontend /app/public/ /var/www/html/public/
```

Comment: If you do `docker history <image name>`, you can see how much space each layer adds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing Docker container size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65072331/reducing-docker-container-size)

Comment: How does your _application_ use `git`, or `curl`, or `xvfb`, while it's running?  Can you trim down that `apt-get install` dependency list to only the things your application actually needs to run?  The `RUN chown` and `RUN chmod` commands also take up more space than they obviously need and probably aren't necessary.

Comment: @DavidMaze I modified my dockerfile to use the multistage build. My image is still big.  I tried using better base images and no more garbage dependencies. Do you have any other suggestions in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is big because it contains all application which you was install via apt-get and their dependencies.

There are multiple ways to solve problem:

- use multistage build
- use suitable base image
- use Alpine linux

##### Multistage build

Use one base image for get/build/test your app and copy needed result to next stage.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS build
*do smth*
FROM php:7.4.27-fpm-alpine AS final
COPY from build...
```

##### Suitable base image

Use image that already contains environment which you need to run application. Where no need to install all these garbage.

##### Use Alpine linux

Use the images which based on Alpine or similar distro, who optimized for docker/clouds, and build your app based on them.

Comment: (If you're installing 1,000 MB of OS packages, the difference between a 5 MB Alpine base and a 50 MB Ubuntu base isn't going to be noticeable, and it comes with some potential compatibility issues.)

Comment: @Ivan I used multistage build and it halved my image size and updated my dockerfile above. But it is still very big. Do you have other suggestions in mind?